# Can a SSH key created by one User ID be used by other ID for SFTP?

Tags: sftp, ssh-keys

I am new to to UNix scipt and SFTP process. I need to write a KSH script by which I can transfer files to a sftp server. I have created the SSH  key pairs. I have developed the KSH code as well. But every time the KSH script is being executed by other ID , its prompting for password where as when I am executing the same it is not asking for any password even though the group id for these 2 user ids are same. Below is my section where I am sending the files

```
###################################################
# SFTP to MFT ---> SFTP to MFT ---> SFTP to MFT   #
###################################################
# Execute SFTP command to PUT a file on MFT       #
#  $1 - SSH Private Key File                      #
#  $2 - SFTP User ID @ MFT Server                 #
#  $3 - Source Directory (to take files from)     #
#  $4 - MFT Directory    (to place files into)    #
#  $5 - File to MPUT                              #
#  $6 - MFT PWD                                   #
###################################################
function sftpputtomft {

sftp -o identityfile=${1} ${2} >> $SFTP_LOG << ENDSFTP
   lcd  ${3}
   cd   ${4}
   mput ${5}
   bye
ENDSFTP
```

Comment: It might be that a ssh key agent helps your normal account not to have to enter the password. But in general that should work. ssh keys have not somehow bound to a specific user id or similar. You only have to make sure the access rights are fine.

Comment: `openssh` checks the permission of private key. If the key is readable by non-owner, it will refuse to use it. It works for you because when you created it, by default `ssh-keygen` creates your key to be readable only by you. Use option `-v -v -v` with `sftp`. This will show what is happening when attempting to connect.

Answer (score 0):

OpemSSH will refuse to use a key that is readable by others. If you try, you will get similar WARNING as below.

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for '/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: /Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I agree with @alvits. I got the same message when I tried out changing permissions to the key files.